# How to select rows where the last entry meets the where condition variable in SQL statement?

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains all the latest test dates for students and the type of test they are taking.

Something like the below:

Joined Table

```
+--------------+--------+--------+
|     Name     |  Test  |  Date  |
+--------------+--------+--------+
| Test Taker A | Math   | May 9  |
| Test Taker B | Math   | May 9  |
| Test Taker A | Math 2 | May 10 |
| Test Taker C | Math   | May 8  |
| Test Taker A | Spanish| May 12 |
+--------------+--------+--------+    

+----------------+---------+-------+
|Registration-ID | Name ID |Test Id|
+----------------+---------+-------+
| 1              | 453     |134534 | 
| 2              | 34534   |134534 |
| 3              | 2343    |134534 | 
| 4              | 453     |12343  |
| 5              | 453     | 4531  |
+--------------+-----------+-------+
+--------------+--------+----+
|Roster  Name  | Name ID|demo|
+--------------+--------+----+
| Test Taker A | 453    | M  |
| Test Taker B | 34534  | F  |
| Test Taker C | 2343   | M  |
+--------------+--------+----+   
+---------+---------+--------+
|Test Name| test ID |Session |
+---------+---------+--------+
| Spanish | 4531    | 3      |
| Math    | 134534  | 2      |
| Math2   | 12343   | 4      |
| Math    | 134534  | 1      |
+---------+---------+--------+   

+------------+-------+
|   Session  |  Date |
+--------------------+
| 2          |  May 9|
| 2          | May 9 |
| 4          | May 10|
| 1          | May 8 |
| 3          |May 12 |
+------------+-------+
```

Right now I have

```
select R.Name, T.Test, D.Date 
from Roster ro
    join registration re on re.name = ro.name
    join test t on t.test_id = re.test_id
    join date d on d.session = t.session
where t.Test = "Math".
```

This will give me Test Taker A,B,C. But I want results to show Tester B and C because the last test they took was Math. I would like the result only if that was last test that person took and there are no further entries.

Apologies for the crappy table, not sure how to format.

Comment: why do you share just one of your 4 tables? if you have isolated the problem to that table, why do you include the other ones in the question?

Comment: Are you storing that HTML in your database?

Comment: Ah sorry, it was so much hassle creating one table I didn't want to go to the effort to creating more. No html, I just don't know how to do table formatting - I can add the other tables if needed. I only use 1 variable from each of the other tables though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `not exists` in your `where` clause with a correlated subquery attempting to seek a *later* test for the *same* test taker which *isn't* `Math`, e.g.:

```
select ro.Name, t.Test, d.Date 
from 
    Roster ro
    join registration re on re.name = ro.name
    join test t on t.test_id = re.test_id
    join date d on d.session = t.session
where 
    t.Test = 'Math' and not exists
    (
        select 1
        from 
            Roster ro2
            join registration re2 on re2.name = ro2.name
            join test t2 on t2.test_id = re2.test_id
            join date d2 on d2.session = t2.session
        where
            ro2.name = ro.name and
            t2.test <> 'Math' and 
            d2.date > d.date
    )
```

---

I believe there is a typo in your original code as there is no alias `r` (used in the `select` clause) and you also join on an alias `ro` which also doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, you have corrected it! So this query only works if there is only 1 more test taken after "Math", if they have multiple ones (say 2 more taken after "Math", that shows up as well.

Comment: @user2532928 I can't see any obvious error in the logic of my query; could you please edit your question to include some sample data for which the query yields the incorrect result, along with the expected result?

Comment: I accidentally put date and id together, so once I fixed it, this works, thanks!